# React - Input in table row loses focus on input

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am working on a refactor of our table system to accommodate dynamic components instead of just text.  I have fixed all of the issues with our old table system except one.  I have an input box within a table row for updating a translation in our database.  Basically each time you type in the input box the input loses focus after one letter.  It appears the whole tree rerenders.  I have a key set on each row I'm creating in the map method.  I have tried every combination of thing I can think of. I tried attaching keys to one element at a time, mixed elements, the whole tree, all using a static `element_UUID` with the UUID being our SQL id UUID which won't change on render.  I have also tried adding name and id attributes to a mix / all of them.  I've tried moving different functions to different places.  I tried using `React.memo` on several components as well. I think I'm potentially missing something about how keys work.  I have attached an example codepen.  I have whittled it down to just the core problem within our table structure.

```js
const startingRows = [
  {
    id: "53b8f2f2-d4ef-4e99-a8bb-bd82c6186e4f",
    key: "login",
    value: "connexion"
  },
  {
    id: "562295c5-be86-4d03-b31f-89127346096d",
    key: "name",
    value: "nom"
  },
  {
    id: "5d3b7d33-bf74-4ea2-ab15-3220ebe9d9e9",
    key: "password",
    value: null
  }
];

const useForm = () => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState({});

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    setInputs((inputs) => ({
      ...inputs,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  return {
    handleInputChange,
    inputs
  };
};

const Show = () => {
  const { inputs, handleInputChange } = useForm();
 
  const tableProps = {
    // Passing in the root components high level state that's required in the TableRows
    TableRow: TableRow({
      inputs,
      handleInputChange
    }),
    rows: { count: 3, records: startingRows }
  };

  return <Table {...tableProps} />;
};

const Table = ({ TableRow, rows: { count, records } }) => {
  return <TableContent TableRow={TableRow} rows={records} />;
};


// It's my understanding that the key below
// attached to the TableRow in the map method
// is what allows React to differeniate between
// what needs to be updated and what doesn't
const TableContent = ({ TableRow, rows }) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Word</th>
          <th>Translation</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {rows && rows.map((row) => <TableRow key={row.id} row={row} />)}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const TableRow = ({ handleInputChange, inputs }) => ({
  // key in this sense means a locale key
  row: { id, key, value }
}) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{key}</td>
      <td>
        <Input
          name={id}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          value={inputs[id] || value}
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};

const Input = ({ id, name, onChange, value }) => {
  return <input name={name} onChange={onChange} value={value} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Show />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-sass@3.4.1/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/rudenate3/pen/oNxPLJm)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code is re-rendering the body tag on input change due to change in the state using `setInputs`. As the state is updated, components is re-rendered again. What you can do is, keep track of the last input/keyup in `startingRows` json and then use it while focusing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add focus back again when component is rendered use ref to do so, change your input component to this. I tried this it is working.

```
const Input = ({ id, name, onChange, value }) => {
     React.useEffect(()=>{
        this.nameInput.focus();
  })
  
  return <input name={name}
           ref={(input) => { this.nameInput = input; }} 
           onChange={onChange} value={value} />;
};
```

Comment: This does seem like a step in the right direction.  For the first one I click into it does keep focus, but once you switch inputs and type a character, it jumps focus to the first one.